# Accessing populated variable outside of function scope js

Tags: javascript

```
var JsonObj = {};
if (Titanium.Network.online) {
  apiHelper.APIPostRequest(APIURL + '/it', tempJSON, function(e) {
    var status = this.status;
    if (status == 200) {
      JsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      //behaves as expected
      //console.log(JsonObj);           
    }
  }, function(err) {
    alert('Unknown error from api');
  });
} else {
  alert('No internet connection found');
}
console.log(JsonObj);
```

When I print it out of the function scope, it returns an empty json object, if I do it within the function it populates it with the relevant data.

I have created a very simple JS file, testing the scope problem and it works:

```
var i=5;

if(i>3){

    if(i>4)
    {


      i = 6;  

    }

}

alert(i);
```

Comment: Could you clarify yuor code, showing us where you declared every variable, and which parts are inside a function?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 4 lines which you posted. Problem is somewhere else

Comment: I have amended the code, nested the original if into a parent if. I find that I do get the populated object fine if I store the variable in the parent if, but not the child if. Any idea why, thanks again.

Comment: -1: You do realize that you haven't defined any functions in the code you posted? - Clean up the code (indentation is horrible so it's largely unreadable), post the example that you say works, and the one that you say doesn't.

Comment: ok, amended the code with code I am actually working on. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has most likely nothing to do with your function scopes.

In most common scenarios with issuing request, you do in asynchronously, that means your console.log executes right after you have issued the request, the function you provide inside the request only executes when you get a response... (Async)

Hence at the time you write out your object at the bottom, the object has not yet been set. As the callback function has not yet been executed.

I highly expect that the apiHelper.APIPostRequest lives up to this pattern. But since I don't have knowledge of any of those frameworks I can't say for sure, but with they way you also describe the error... It's the only obvious thing i can see.

---

```
var JsonObj = {};
console.log("Before Async Request: " + JsonObj);
if (Titanium.Network.online) {
  apiHelper.APIPostRequest(APIURL + '/it', tempJSON, function(e) {
    var status = this.status;
    if (status == 200) {
      JsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      console.log("Inside Async Callback: " + JsonObj);
      //behaves as expected
      //console.log(JsonObj);           
    }
  }, function(err) {
    alert('Unknown error from api');
  });
} else {
  alert('No internet connection found');
}
console.log("After Async Request: " + JsonObj);
```

---

You may as well start to learn about Promises right away... E.g. with Q it should go something like this:

```
var deferred = Q.defer(),
    JsonObj = deferred.promise;
if (Titanium.Network.online) {
  apiHelper.APIPostRequest(APIURL + '/it', tempJSON, function(e) {
    var status = this.status;
    if (status == 200) {
      deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
    }
  }, function(err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });
} else {
  alert('No internet connection found');
}

JsonObj.then(function(json) {
  console.log("After Async Request: " + json);
});
```

Comment: Jens, thanks for that.
But isn't the console.log run after the async method is called? (the whole snippet of code should be executed procedurally) So if the async method is called, I get a response and set the JSONObject shouldn't I then be able to access that populated object later on outside of the async method?

Comment: No, if it is an async function which is highly likely here, your just instructing it to execute a function when it's done (in this case when it has gotten a response) and then your code continues without caring about when that happens. Try to run the sample I posted, you will notice the order of the events.

Comment: Right, so how can I access the JSONObject for later use outside of the async function?

Comment: You begin to learn about promises: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/, note that that link is to ES6, so you need to rely on one of the many other implemantioans out there... such as q: http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/, jquery: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/ etc.

Comment: Looks as though this is jquery based, titanium does not support it. Is it good practice if I nest the rest of my code inside the async function? (within the if)

Comment: You obviously need to download and include the Q library for the above to work, but if jQuery is already available you can just use their promise library instead. you create a deffered with `new jQuery.Deferred();` and access the promise with `deffered.promise()` instead.

And no, I would consider it as a bad practice to nest the rest of your code in the callback, the first one is ok but soon you will have things so deeply nested and it doesn't improve readability.

If your lucky the APIPostRequest might already return a promise, otherwise I would wrap it into something that does.